# Invoke methodinfo inherited from closed generic

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

```
 private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var messageType = typeof (SampleHandler1);
        var genericType = typeof (IConsume<>).MakeGenericType(messageType);
        var genericArguments = genericType.GetGenericArguments();
        var consumeMethod = genericType.GetMethod("Consume");

        var constructorInfo = genericArguments[0].GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        var classObject = constructorInfo.Invoke(new object[] {});

        var argsx = new object[] {new SampleMessage {Name = "sample message"}};

        consumeMethod.Invoke(classObject, argsx);
    }

public interface IConsume<in T> where T : class
{
    void Consume(T message);
}

public class SampleHandler1 : IConsume<SampleMessage>
{
    public SampleHandler1()
    {
        Debugger.Break();
    }

    public void Consume(SampleMessage message)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        Console.WriteLine("Message consume: " + message.Name);
    }
}


public interface IBaseMessage
{
}

public class SampleMessage : IBaseMessage
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I tried looking here but I cant find specific solution. As [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx) explains

> obj
>   Type: System.Object
>   The object on which to invoke the method or constructor. If a method is static, this argument is ignored. If a constructor is static, this argument must be null or an instance of the class that defines the constructor.

classObject is an instance of constructor, right? Why it throws an exception: [image]

Comment: I think your question may be missing some elements.  Is IBaseMessage suppose to have a `Name` property declared on it?

Answer (score 4):

That doesn't seem right. Let's analyze what's happening here:

```
var messageType = typeof (SampleHandler1);
//simple enough, Type -> SampleHandler1

var genericType = typeof (IConsume<>).MakeGenericType(messageType);
//so genericType is a Type -> IConsume<SampleHandler1>

var genericArguments = genericType.GetGenericArguments();
//there's only one, but Type[] { Type -> SampleHandler1 }

var consumeMethod = genericType.GetMethod("Consume");
//MethodInfo -> IConsume<SampleHandler1>.Consume(SampleHandler1)

var constructorInfo = genericArguments[0].GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
//ConstructorInfo -> SampleHandler1..ctor()

var classObject = constructorInfo.Invoke(new object[] {});
//new SampleHandler1()

var argsx = new object[] {new SampleMessage {Name = "sample message"}};
//object[] { SampleMessage }

consumeMethod.Invoke(classObject, argsx);
//((IConsume<SampleHandler1>)classObject).Consume( SampleMessage ) -- oops?
```

So `classObject` is an `SampleHandler1`, but you're trying to invoke `IConsume<SampleHandler1>.Consume(SampleHandler1)` and worse yet give it a `SampleMessage` as an argument.

I think you meant to create a `SampleHandler1`, and invoke `IConsume<SampleMessage>.Consume(SampleMessage)` on it:

```
var messageType = typeof(SampleMessage);
var genericType = typeof(IConsume<>).MakeGenericType(messageType);
var consumeMethod = genericType.GetMethod("Consume");

var handlerType = typeof(SampleHandler1);
var constructorInfo = handlerType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
var classObject = constructorInfo.Invoke(new object[] {});

var argsx = new object[] {new SampleMessage {Name = "sample message"}};

consumeMethod.Invoke(classObject, argsx);
```

Comment: Ok; in my understanding is bit off, so it must make generic type from SampleMessage then create a type from SampleHandler1 then pass the argument into it. for my understanding get the SampleHandler1  first then construct the type and invoke.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but based on all of the components you have in your question, I suspect that you are looking for something more like this:

using System;

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var handlerType = typeof (SampleHandler1);
        var genericType = handlerType.GetInterface("IConsume`1");
        var genericArguments = genericType.GetGenericArguments();
        var consumeMethod = genericType.GetMethod("Consume");

        var handlerConstructorInfo = handlerType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        var handler = handlerConstructorInfo.Invoke(new object[] {});

        var messageConstructorInfo = genericArguments[0].GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        var messageObject = messageConstructorInfo.Invoke(new object[] {});

        ((IBaseMessage)messageObject).Name = "Sample Message";

        var argsx = new object[] {messageObject};

        consumeMethod.Invoke(handler, argsx);

    }
}

public interface IConsume<in T> where T : class, IBaseMessage
{
    void Consume(T message);
}

public class SampleHandler1 : IConsume<SampleMessage>
{
    public SampleHandler1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SampleHandler1 constructed");
    }

    public void Consume(SampleMessage message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Message consume: " + message.Name);
    }
}


public interface IBaseMessage
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SampleMessage : IBaseMessage
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a working Dotnetfiddle of the above answer: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YFmmzk

The console output is:

> SampleHandler1 constructed
>
> Message consume: Sample Message

It looks like you were getting your handler and message types confused.  You were trying to pass an instance of the handler itself to the consume method.  More over, IBaseMessage was missing the `Name` property declaration.

**UPDATE**

Here is a [cleaned](http://www.bitnative.com/presentations/clean-code-writing-code-for-humans/) up version of this answer:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var handler = new DynamicConstructor(typeof (SampleHandler1)).New();
        invokeIConsumeFor(handler, "Sample Message");
    }

    private static void invokeIConsumeFor(object handler, string message)
    {
        var executer      = new DynamicGenericInterfaceExecuter(handler, "IConsume`1");
        var messageObject = executer.GetTypeArgumentConstructor(0, Type.EmptyTypes).New();

        ((IBaseMessage) messageObject).Name = message;

        executer.Method("Consume", messageObject.GetType()).Call(messageObject);
    }
}

public class DynamicGenericInterfaceExecuter
{
    private object instance;
    private Type genericInterfaceFromType;
    private Type[] genericTypeArguments;
    
    public DynamicGenericInterfaceExecuter(object instance, string interfaceName)
    {
        this.instance                 = instance;
        this.genericInterfaceFromType = instance.GetType().GetInterface(interfaceName);
        this.genericTypeArguments     = this.genericInterfaceFromType.GetGenericArguments();
    }

    public MethodExecuter Method(string methodName, params Type[] parameterTypes)
    {
        return new MethodExecuter(this.instance, this.genericInterfaceFromType, methodName, parameterTypes);
    }

    public DynamicConstructor GetTypeArgumentConstructor(int typeArgumentIndex, params Type[] constructorParameterTypes)
    {
        return new DynamicConstructor(this.genericTypeArguments[typeArgumentIndex], constructorParameterTypes);
    }
}

public class DynamicConstructor
{
    private System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor;

    public DynamicConstructor(Type type, params Type[] constructorParameters)
    {
        this.constructor = type.GetConstructor(constructorParameters);
    }

    public object New(params object[] constructorArguments)
    {
        return this.constructor.Invoke(constructorArguments);
    }
}

public class MethodExecuter
{
    private object instance;
    private System.Reflection.MethodInfo method;

    public MethodExecuter(object instance, Type containerType, string methodName, Type[] methodParameters)
    {
        this.instance = instance;
        this.method   = containerType.GetMethod(methodName, methodParameters);
    }

    public void Call(params object[] arguments)
    {
        this.Invoke(arguments);
    }

    public object Invoke(params object[] arguments)
    {
        return this.method.Invoke(instance, arguments);
    }
}

public interface IConsume<in T> where T : class, IBaseMessage
{
    void Consume(T message);
}

public class SampleHandler1 : IConsume<SampleMessage>
{
    public SampleHandler1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SampleHandler1 constructed");
    }

    public void Consume(SampleMessage message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Message consume: " + message.Name);
    }
}

public interface IBaseMessage
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SampleMessage : IBaseMessage
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And the dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/n9WHZ2

Keep in mind that this is not type safe in the slightest, but that does not appear to be a concern in your question.